# Checking for input while sleeping

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, c++14

Two functions: CheckInput and SendKey

CheckInput checks for Alt-J to be pressed. When Alt-J is pressed, a bool is toggled which allows for SendKey to keep sending the Enter key every 500ms.

I need for CheckInput to still be able to get user input and change the bool - thus stopping enter being sent - whilst the SendKey is still waiting within the sleep, otherwise right now I have to hold down Alt-J until the next 500ms is up.

Any ideas on how to do this? It just seems so basic yet I can't wrap my head around it...

( Basically, a script that presses enter every 500ms and can be toggled on and off without needing to wait 500ms )

```
void CheckInput() {
    if ((GetKeyState(0x12) & 0x8000) && (GetKeyState(0x4A) & 0x8000)) {
        Active = !Active;
    }
}

void SendKey() {
    if (Active) {
        keybd_event(0x0D, 0x0A, 0, 0);
        Sleep(16);
        keybd_event(0x0D, 0X0A, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        Sleep(500);
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (1) {
        thread t1(CheckInput);
        thread t2(SendKey);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well regardless of solution, you should have the loops in the threads, not in the main function.

Comment: Exactly. Both threads should have their own loop. And you can do the main processing on the main thread; you just need the flag management on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenter mentioned, you need to put your loops in the threads, like in this example:

```
atomic_int  temp;

std::thread t( [&temp]()
              {

                  while( temp!= -1){
                      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
                      temp=0;
                  }
              });
```

You can use a condition variable and have one thread to wait upon it.

The second thread(or the main loop) would wait for the keyboard input in a loop and signal the condition variable once the input arrives.

Comment: I don't want any of the threads to wait upon each other. For example, I would want CheckInput and SendKey to both run at the same times, as if they were two while loops running on independent threads seperate to each other, so if one thread sleeps the other can still keep checking for input.

Comment: Yes with some exit conditions. Avoid data races by using atomic variables. Waiting on a condition variable for the key press would avoid having two threads spinning instead of just one.

Comment: I've tried to move the loops to the actual functions, but the sleep(500) inside SendKeys still makes the entire program have to wait for it so I still have to wait 500ms before my input by CheckInput is registered

Comment: Have SendKeys wait on a condition variable, this way you can wake up the thread immediately, there is a good example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: Like I said, it's not the threads waking up too late, it's the fact that by sleeping within SendKeys, CheckInput is also blocked, however I need the delay in SendKeys since I only want it to be run every 500ms, and if I put a delay of 500ms anywhere in the program, then EVERYTHING has to wait for that. The same thing applies with condition variables, since I still want to keep both functions going and not have either to wait for the other one.

Comment: While the sendkeys is waiting for 500ms, I still want checkinput to work, yet the sleep(500) just dead-stops the program.

Comment: You have two separate threads, one can wait, the other can check for input all the time. Your threads are not well implemented as they are, that is why sleep is blocking.

Comment: However, I don't actually have two separate threads. While one waits, the other one will also wait. I have no idea on how the other one can check for input all the time when it won't even run.

Answer (score 1):

This would go much smoother if you could use a Windows event loop.

If you can't, you should simulate it.

Create a thread-safe queue that can store event information. You need two types of events - keystrokes and timer ticks.

One thread will sleep for 500ms and send a timer tick event - in a loop. The other thread will call `Console.ReadKey` and send a keystroke event - also in a loop.

Your main thread will wait for events to arrive from the queue and handle them.

Comment: This is basically what I want to do, but I can't figure out how to make one thread sleep for 500ms while still allowing the other thread to be able to continue. It's as if any way I multi-thread, it still acts as one thread going in sequence when really I need parallel.

Comment: Start two threads. One of them will sleep and the other won't. That's what threads are all about.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out to just check if the time since last time that Enter was pressed is over 500ms ago, so that it works off of system-time. Unfortunately I still have'nt found a way to have two simultaneous processes running at once, but this seems to work like I needed it to:

```
void SendKey() {
    if (Active){
        keybd_event(0x0D, 0x0A, 0, 0);
        Sleep(16);
        keybd_event(0x0D, 0X0A, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    }
}

void CheckInput() {
    auto t1 = Clock::now() + chrono::seconds(1);
    int temp = 0;
    while (temp == 0) {
        if ((GetKeyState(0x12) & 0x8000) && (GetKeyState(0x4A) & 0x8000)) {
            Active = !Active;
        }
        if (Clock::now() > t1) {
            SendKey();
            temp = 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (1) {
        thread t1(CheckInput);
        t1.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This basically stores the time that CheckInput was run at, and sets a set goal thats 1 second in the future. Then it will just keep checking the inputs and it will also check if the time has passed that set goal, which when it has, then it will call SendKey, before repeating again.

Comment: Putting didiz's answer as the solution since he helped the most and reminded me of the chrono::milliseconds, but for my needs this works.

Comment: The loop is still creating and destroying a thread every time it runs is that intended?